# How to use DynamicObject in model csharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Can I use DynamicObject in model. I wanna use it in razor page. is it possible ?

```
public class ProductsModel
    {
        public ProductDetail ProductDetail { get; set; } 
        public MyDynamicClass  
    }
```

The following simple example allows adding of arbitrary dynamic properties at runtime. The class overrides the TrySetMember and TryGetMember virtual methods to provide the behaviour. Notice that these methods have a binder parameter that gives information about the dynamic operation that is being attempted, such as the name of the property (binder.Name). Also note that the methods return a Boolean value to indicate to the runtime whether the dynamic operation succeeded.

```
class MyDynamicClass : DynamicObject
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _dynamicProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        _dynamicProperties.Add(binder.Name, value);

        // additional error checking code omitted

        return true;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        return _dynamicProperties.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var property in _dynamicProperties)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"Property '{property.Key}' = '{property.Value}'");
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        return _dynamicProperties.Keys;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use DynamicObject in model. I wanna use it in razor page. is it
> possible ?

This is possible, but first you have to standardize the writing of ProductsModel, as [@Jawad said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62917454/12884742).

```
   public class ProductsModel
   {
            public ProductDetail ProductDetail { get; set; }
            public MyDynamicClass myDynamic { get; set; }
   }

    public class ProductDetail
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
    }
```

Then, to ensure that the ProductsModel data can be displayed on the page, then you need to add the **Dictionary<string, object> field** to `MyDynamicClass`, so that you can get the data of the dynamic fields under MyDynamicClass.

MyDynamicClass:

```
 public class MyDynamicClass : DynamicObject
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _dynamicProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

       public MyDynamicClass()
       {
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          {
              _dynamicProperties.Add("Id" + i, i);
              _dynamicProperties.Add("Value" + i, "Value" + i);
          }
       }

        // This property returns the number of elements
        // in the inner dictionary.s
        public Dictionary<string, object> MyData
        {
            get
            {
                return _dynamicProperties;
            }
        }

        public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
        {
            _dynamicProperties.Add(binder.Name, value);

            // additional error checking code omitted

            return true;
        }
        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            return _dynamicProperties.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var property in _dynamicProperties)
            {
                sb.AppendLine($"Property '{property.Key}' = '{property.Value}'");
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
        public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
        {
            return _dynamicProperties.Keys;
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
   public class IndexModel : PageModel
    { 
        [BindProperty]
        public ProductsModel data { get; set; } 
        public void OnGet()
        {
            dynamic formData = new MyDynamicClass(); 

            data = new ProductsModel()
            {
                myDynamic = formData,
                ProductDetail = new ProductDetail() { Id = 1, Details = "aaaaaaaaa" }
            };

        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
<h1>DynamicTest</h1>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>

        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => Model.data.ProductDetail.Id)</th>
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => Model.data.ProductDetail.Details)</th>
        @foreach (var item in Model.data.myDynamic.MyData)
        {
            <th> @item.Key</th>
        }
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> @Model.data.ProductDetail.Id</td>
        <td> @Model.data.ProductDetail.Details</td>
        @foreach (var item in Model.data.myDynamic.MyData)
        {
            <td> <input asp-for="@item.Value" />  </td>
        }
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the test result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the name of the property. The way you have it, `public MyDynamicClass` is invalid code and must have a property name. `public MyDynamicClass MyObject`. Then you can use the getter and setter to set up the value

Answer (score 0):

can I set it in Constructor ? I wanna use in razpor page for form

```
    <form method="post">
        <input asp-for="MyDynamicClass.Id1" /> 
        <input asp-for="MyDynamicClass.Value1" />
             <input type="button" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

how and where can set it

```
public class MyDynamicClass : DynamicObject
{
    public MyDynamicClass()
    {
        dynamic d = new MyDynamicClass();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            d["Id" + 1] = 0;
            d["Value" + 1] = string.Empty;

        }
    }
    //....
}
```

Comment: You want to dynamically bind different fields to
MyDynamicClass?
If so, you can implement it in the constructor of MyDynamicClass, but you can only add it by adding data to the `Dictionary`, not the `d["Id" + 1]` array form.

And you need to know that MyDynamicClass is basically custom dynamic class. According to the method, it can be seen that it is actually the type of `Dictionary` in the end, so you cannot use the asp-for form to bind the value of `MyDynamicClass.Id1` field, I suggest you use my code for testing, I have updated my reply.